# Publish rdbms table record in kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a workflow where upstream is generating a data and transformer module applies some business logic on it and store the result in table. Now requirement is I need to publish that result into Kafka topic

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Debezium to pull CDC logs from a few supported databases into a Kafka topic.

Otherwise, Kafka Connect offers many plugins for different data sources, and Confluent Hub is a sort of index where you can search for those

Otherwise, simply make your data generator into a Kafka producer instead of just a database client